# mvn archetype:generate using internal maven repo

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I wanted to create a maven project using "mvn archetype:generate ..." to create a maven project Skeleton. I looked up online and come up with this:

in settings.xml

```
<profile>
    <id>PlatMigr</id>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>internal repo</id>
            <name>IT Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://<internal maven repo></url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```

From command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=internal -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.myproj -DartifactId=ProjName
```

However maven still tried to download artifacts from official central maven repo:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
```

We have a firewall installed to stop internet access, that's why I struggle to use internal repo in the first place. Anyone can advise on how to setup and use internal repo to create maven projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit you settings.xml in m2_home, add mirror to you nexus and create & set to active  profile without central repositories